# CSS animation on changing list order with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, state

In my React app, I have a 'Ranking' page. It has a list that could be sorted based on few criteria.
I want to add a simple CSS animation, so that when sorting criteria is changed items old list fades-out and newly sorted list fades-in, instead of changing abruptly and instantly.

I've managed to get the list to animate on initial page load. But when sorting criteria is changed, the list changes instantly. I recon it might be due to me not quite getting how React state work. Your help - or link to manuals which could clarify the matter - is much appreciated.

JS with unnecessary code taken away:

```
function Ranking() {

const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [sortType, setSortType] = useState();
const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = useState();

// load items once on page load
useEffect(() => {
    loadItems();
}, [])

// fetch items from api
function loadItems() {
    fetch(
        `/api/get`,
        {
            method: "GET",
            mode: "cors"
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setItems((prevItems) => {
                return [...prevItems, ...data] })
                })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

// sort items based on current sort type
function sortItems(type) {
    console.log('starting sort...')
    setIsSorted(false);
    console.log('set isSorted to false: ', isSorted)
    if (type === 1) {
        return items.sort((a, b) => b.criteria1 - a.criteria1);
    } else if (type === 2) {
        return items.sort((a, b) => b.criteria2 - a.criteria2);
    } else if (type === 3) {
        return items.sort((a, b) => b.criteria3 - a.criteria3);
    };
}


// sort items on render
useEffect(() => {
    if (!sortType) {
        setSortType(1);
    }
    if (items.length > 0) {
        setItems(sortItems(sortType));
        setIsSorted(true);
    }
})

// when 'Criteria N' button is clicked, change sorting criteria accordingly
function handleSort(event) {
    const name = event.target.name;
    setIsSorted(() => {
        setSortType(parseInt(name));
        return false;
    });
}

return <div className="ranking-container">
            <button className="ranking-sort-btn" name="1" onClick={handleSort}>Criteria 1</button>
            <button className="ranking-sort-btn" name="2" onClick={handleSort}>Criteria 2</button>
            <button className="ranking-sort-btn" name="3" onClick={handleSort}>Criteria 3</button>
            <div className={isSorted ? "ranking-item-loaded" : "ranking-item-not-loaded"}>
                {items.map((item, index) => {
                        return <RankingItem item={item} key={index} isSorted={isSorted}/>   
                    })
                }
            </div>
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ranking-item-not-loaded {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 200ms ease-in;
}

.ranking-item-loaded {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 220ms ease-in;    
}
```

Comment: You can use `onAnimationEnd` synthetic event to be notified when an animation ends.

Comment: Thank you. onTransitionEnd event clarified the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out transitions were abruptly interrupted by state changes.
Switching from transition to proper animation which did not rely on second state solved the problem.

```
<div className={isSorted && "ranking-item-animated"} onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}>
```

```
.ranking-item-animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: fadein;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```